# JavaScript not responding to onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle the visibilty of a navigation list with a "burger"/`<img>` button.

```
<img onclick="dropdownMenu()" class="burger" src="img/icon/menu.png"></img>
```

I want this button to fire off this script wich is placed in `<head>` and inside a `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
        function dropdownMenu() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("nav").classList.toggle("show");
        }
</script>
```

The menu looks like this.

```
<nav>
     <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
          <li><a href="store.php">Festivaler</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

I've had tried with `.classList.toggle("show");` and `.style.display = "none";` and also done some simple testing with changing the color.
Is my syntax wrong or is it something else?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList, not an element

Comment: okay, thank you i will read up on that. What should i use to return an element?

Comment: Edit: I have also tried using .getElementByID and .getElementByClassname

Comment: Look at your console and view the errors displayed there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of DOM elements, to get a single one you must select the item from the list. That being said:

```
function dropdownMenu() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but even using this my navigation doesn't toggle its visibility.

Comment: Can you show me some bit of your CSS code, to take a look?

Comment: `/* Navigationens stilregler */
.burger {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 height: 100px;
 width: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
 color:  red;
}`

Comment: I'm on mobile, can't format the comment, but: You should hide .burger from the start .burger{ display: none} and add another CSS rule to make it visible .burger.show{ display: block }

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a getElementByTag, look to using an ID to select the tag more explictly; finding by class or by tag will return a collection, whereas finding by ID will return an element.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Once you have the item by ID you'll need to use style.display = "none"; or include Jquery and then you can use the toggle, in which case you would also just find the element with a Jquery selector.

Comment: Ahhaaa okay, sounds really smart. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, im getting this error:  TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

Comment: It is document.getElementById not document.getElementsById

Answer (score 0):

I think its done now.

```
 <script>
        function nav(){
            document.getElementById("nav").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    </script>

<img onclick="nav()" class="burger" src="img/icon/menu.png"></img>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <!-- navigationslista -->
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="store.php">Festivaler</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

I just have to make it toggle. Thank you guys. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that toggles:

```
<nav id="nav1">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
          <li><a href="store.php">Festivaler</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>

<script>
        function dropdownMenu() {
          document.getElementById("nav1").classList.toggle("show");
        }
</script>

<style>
.show {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I guess the problem was, that there was no .show class in the CSS. With a .show class just get the menu with getElementByID and toggle the class.